# Find the sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n-1}{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n-1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Fill in details in the following:

$$|x|<1\implies\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\implies\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2nx^n$$

and now choose and sustitute in the above $\;x=...\;$ and then...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}
$$
and $x$ times its derivative
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly an absolutely convergent series, hence by setting $S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n-1}{2^n}$ we have:
$$ 2S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n-1}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2(n-1)-1)+2}{2^{n-1}}=4+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2(n-1)-1}{2^{n-1}} $$
or $ 2S = 3+S$, from which $\color{red}{S=3}$.